# django - When fields are flexible at creation time

Tags: python, django

I want to create a "Matching Partner" model with data called "partner."

[request "partner" data]

```
"partner": [
    {
        "user_nm": "1",
        "user_gender": "F"
    },
    {
        "user_nm": "2",
        "user_gender": "F"            
    }
]
```

There's multiple instances of it going around the code, and if that's the case,

"partner": {
"user_nm": "sevia"}

In this way, when data is passed over, fields other than "user_nm" would like to be stored as null.

```
        if request.data:
        partners = request.data["partner"]
        for partner in partners:
            Partner.objects.create(
                matching=matching_instance,
                user_nm=partner["user_nm"],
                user_gender=partner["user_gender"],
            )
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). dict.get() return the value for key if the key is in the dictionary, else default. If the default is not given(as our case), it defaults to None.

```
if request.data:
    partners = request.data["partner"]
    for partner in partners:
        MatchingPartner.objects.create(
            matching=matching_instance,
            non_user_nm=partner.get("non_user_nm"),
            non_user_gender=partner.get("non_user_gender"),
        )
```

Comment: There are 6 fields in total, is there any more efficient way than writing down "if"?